# Scala List append operation - need explaination

Tags: scala

Based on the explanation and my understanding on the List append operation in scala it is right associative. So given a statement
List1 ::: List2 is nothing but List2.:::List1. With this said i tried to do following operations

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3,4) 
val list2 = List(5,6,7,8)  
list1 ::: list2 // this is good

list2.::: list1 //ERROR - Not applicable to List[B]code here
```

Why does not the second append operation compile?

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis. Try `list2.:::(list1)`.

Comment: that worked. But what trick did that extra () do? How does it help compiler to understand the statement?

Comment: `list2.::: list1` is invalid Scala syntax. You must either use the parenthesis (like `list2.:::(list1)`), or use infix notation like you originally did (like `list1 ::: list2`). With this specific function, the infix notation has `list1` written first because the function is right associative. Functions with a name ending with a colon are right associative in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not compile is because there's a mix and math with the syntax there.
you can use the regular syntax for method invocation:

`list2.:::(list1)`

Notice the dot AND the parenthesis.

Or you can use the infix notation for invoking methods of arity-1:

`list1 ::: list2`

But you cant mix between the two.

The `:::` operator is actually a prepend and not append operator,
it operates on list2 (as you stated correctly it is right associative) and adds the elements of list1 in front of it.